# jquery ui slider cloning issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a main div and inside that div there are a couple of other elements, including a sliderdiv. I am trying to clone the main div n number of times. All other elements are working fine except the cloned slider.  Every time I try to slide the cloned one, the first slider moves.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slider').slider();

    $('#btn').click(function () {

        //here finding total number of main div, cloning the last added div 
        var currentCount = $('.repeatingSection').length;
        var lastRepeatingGroup = $('.repeatingSection').last();
        var lastdivID = lastRepeatingGroup.attr('id');
        var cloneddiv = lastRepeatingGroup.clone(true, true);

        //changing the main div id
        $(cloneddiv).attr('id', lastdivID + currentCount);

        //calling a method to change ID of all the elements inside the cloned div
        ChangeClonedDivWithNewID(cloneddiv, currentCount);
        //adding cloned div at the end   
        cloneddiv.insertAfter(lastRepeatingGroup);
        return false;
    });

    function CreateSlider(sliderdivID) {
        $("#" + slider).slider();
    }

    function ChangeClonedDivWithNewID(elem, counter) {
        alert("enterred into function");
        $(elem).find("[id]").each(function () {
            this.id = this.id + counter;
            var x = this.id;
            //checking for div with slider id and then adding slider to cloned div
            if (this.id == "slider" + counter) {
                CreateSlider(this.id);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

html

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="repeatingSection" id="repeatdiv">
    <div id="slider" class="sliderclass">
    </div>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="gender" class="ddgender" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
        <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="-1" Selected="true"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="male" Value="1" Selected="False"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="female" Value="0" Selected="False"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <label id="add" class="add">
        Add New</label>
    <label id="remove" class="remove">
        Remove</label>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="btn" Text="clone" runat="server" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am Posting a solution to my own issue. I found a way around.

1. Clone the parent div containing slider div and other elements.
2. Delete the slider div from the cloned parent div
3. Add new div to the parent div to replace deleted div

   Here is  my working code:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   CreateSlider("slider");
   $('.add').click(function(){


   var currentCount = $('.repeatingSection').length;
   var lastRepeatingGroup = $('.repeatingSection').last();
   var lastdivID = lastRepeatingGroup.attr('id');
   var cloneddiv = lastRepeatingGroup.clone(true, true);

   //changing the main div id
   $(cloneddiv).attr('id', lastdivID + currentCount);

   //Deleting Slider div from cloned parent div
     $(cloneddiv).find('.sliderclass').remove();


   //calling a method to change ID of all the elements inside the cloned div
   ChangeClonedDivWithNewID(cloneddiv, currentCount);

   //Creating a new div and adding it to cloned parent div
      var div = $("<div>", { id: "slider"+ currentCount, class: "sliderclass" });
       $(cloneddiv).prepend(div);

   //adding cloned div at the end   
   cloneddiv.insertAfter(lastRepeatingGroup);

   //add slider to the cloned parent div
       CreateSlider($(div).attr('id'));
       return false;
   });

   function CreateSlider(sliderdivID) {
       $("#" + slider).slider();
   }

   function ChangeClonedDivWithNewID(elem, counter) {
       $(elem).find("[id]").each(function () {
       this.id = this.id + counter;
       var x = this.id;

   });
   ```

   }
       });